# <source> tag not working in Laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, image, laravel-5, srcset

### Issue:

I am trying to use `<source>` tag to display my images in **Laravel blade**.

```
<picture>
   <source srcset="{{asset('images/img1.webp')}}" type="image/webp">
   <source srcset="{{asset('images/img1.png')}}" type="image/png"> 
</picture>
```

But **the image isn't showing**. There is no error in the browser console either.

### What I have tried:

If I view page source, the code is there and the image path is also correct. I am using **Laravel 5.8.32**.

I have used the same code in other **non-laravel** project, like such:

```
<picture>
   <source srcset="/images/img1.webp" type="image/webp">
   <source srcset="/images/img1.png" type="image/png"> 
</picture>
```

and it worked perfectly.
I also tried this path in Laravel but it's still not working.

**How can I get it working? Or is `source` tag not supported in blade?**

Comment: Are you using a browser (version) which understands the picture and source tags?

Comment: check the html source of the page, copy the srcset url in a browser and see if you can get the image

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=source - only 3 browsers actually support it...

Comment: @AndyHolmes it's actually https://caniuse.com/#feat=picture which is widely supported

Comment: I am using Chrome 76, which seems to support these tags according to the [Support Table](https://caniuse.com/#search=picture)

Comment: File permissions maybe? Have you tried using a regular `<img>` tag instead? Do the images show up there?